# `fourfoldplot` not displaying size and colors correctly with numbers in column labels

Tags: r, plot, confusion-matrix

If I use a sample table, like so:

`ctable <- as.table(matrix(c(42, 6, 8, 28), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE))`

and plot with `fourfoldplot(ctable)`, I see all fine:

[image]

However if I try with my table, it doesn't works:

[image]

Printing my table on terminal, the only difference is the label of the columns:

```
   pred
     1  2
  1 78  9
  2 37  6
```

Is there a way to plot with numeric labels? Or is there other error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot you have is correct, the rings are confidence rings for odds ratio, so if your observed counts are very similar to your expected counts, then the rings will touch one another. Here's one way to look at it, I do the same fourfoldplot and label each quadrant with the expected counts (from chisq.test). It is colored turquoise if less than expected, and red is more than expected:

```
plot_w_chisq = function(i){
fourfoldplot(i)
csq = chisq.test(i)
expected=round(c(csq$expected))
obs=c(i)
cols = ifelse(expected/obs>1,"turquoise","brown")
text(x=c(-0.8,-0.8,0.8,0.8),y=c(0.8,-0.8,0.8,-0.8),label=expected,col=cols)
}
plot_w_chisq(ctable)
```

[image]

Using your example:

```
ntable = structure(c(78, 37, 9, 6), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2"), c("1", "2")), class = "table")

plot_w_chisq(ntable)
```

[image]

You can see the observed does not deviate much from your observed, hence the plot.